# How to remove a inner square brackets from JSON using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I Have JSON String like below and i need to remove  the square brackets .Used code to produce JSOn from CSV.

```
lines=read from csv
def payload = []

lines.each { line ->
    def contractor = line.split(',')
      payload.add(contractor as String )    
}
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
 log.info(vars.get('payload'))
```

**Produced JSON :**

```
[
"[abc]",
"[Jagan1]",
"[Jagan2]",
"[Jagan3]"]
```

I need a JSON like Below:
["abc","jagan1","jagan2","jagan3"]

Comment: It really depends on input csv. The easiest change: `def contractor = line.split(',')[0]`

Comment: Agree that showing us your CSV fomat is probably required for a non-guess answer